# URL Rewrite not available after installing on IIS 10

Tags: iis, rewrite

I can't seem to find anything about this online.

I've **installed [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)** via [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) on Windows 10  running IIS 10, **restarted IIS Manager**, **restarted IIS Server** and also **rebooted my machine** but URL Rewrite option is **still not available** under `Site` -> `IIS` category.

I also found a post saying to check if `rewrite.dll` is available under `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` and it is.

I also tried reinstalling it, but can't seem to find a way to uninstall.

Any ideas as to why this is happening to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out that `URL Rewrite` can be uninstalled via `Add or Remove Programs`. Apparently its named `IIS URL Rewrite Module 2` and not `Microsoft URL Rewrite Module` which a lot of posts suggest.

After uninstalling I installed it again via `Web Platform Installer`, restarted `IIS Manager` and now its available under `IIS` category.

Hope this helps some of you out there.

Comment: That seems like a broken installer; the same thing just happened to me; why did i have to install it twice to get it to work..weird

Comment: Same for me. After it didn't work with the first install, I had to uninstall via Add/Remove Programs and install again via Web Platform Installer. Thank you.

Comment: Simply clicking 'Repair' rather than doing a full reinstall was enough for me, I've had it happen twice now, think it may well be an installer bug.

Comment: Whatever was wrong seems to have been fixed. I only had to restart IIS Manager after installing the rewrite module once.

Answer (score 3):

I have a bad feeling some of these technologies are being deprecated without mention. I was looking at IISNode as we have some apps that run on IIS, and it seemed like a good idea, but installing has been rough. URL Rewrite is needed for it, which led me here.

Searching Microsoft's site is getting tough, from the main link they didn't have IIS 10 and URL Rewrite. lol.

If you go here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite there is an option to install the URL Rewrite via .MSI and not via the Web Platform Installer (second link, bottom of the page). They are up to a 2.1 version it looks like, although oddly when you install the MSI, the title page says "2" (no dot #).

I did have to exit the IIS manager and restart, but the URL rewrite showed right up. No registry hacks, didn't have to install it twice.

As with Homan Chu, I've had problems with the WPI on protected servers also, a stand alone .MSI is a lot easier. Hopefully the iis.net link will work for you!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue on Windows Server 2016 IIS 10. Since I have no internet access on that server, I cannot use the  webapi installer. I solved it by running the installer again and choose repair.